# jQuery: Loading html file from the server in desktop application

Tags: jquery, load, desktop-application

is it possible to create a **html/jquery desktop application** that reads **html** files from my server/website?

Thank you. F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, jQuery runs inside whatever's running JavaScript (*usually* a browser), it is not a standalone application.  If you have something else that is a browser (or a browser control, many frameworks have this) then you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at creating a PHP desktop app that uses GTK! Or create a Java applet?